# what is the purpose of Print Scaling in the page layout tab in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

What is the purpose of Print Scaling in the page layout tab in Excel?

in the Width and Height I can select Automatic and options like 1 or 2 pages and others. but I don't know its purpose.

Is it used at print time? Does it mean that it prints two page in one paper or vice-versa?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What is the purpose of Print Scaling in the page layout tab in Excel?

> Use the Scale to Fit settings in Excel 2007 if you need to make a worksheet fit to get a few last rows or columns on a single page.
>
> You can use the Width, Height, and Scale options in the Scale to Fit group of the Page Layout tab to change these settings. These options are also available on the Page tab of the Page Setup dialog box.
>
> Don’t try to shrink the document too much. Trying to fit too much on a page can make the document too small to read. If you decide to cancel the scaling, select Automatic for the Width and Height settings on the Page Layout tab and set the Scale back to 100%.

Source [How to Use Excel 2007’s Scale to Fit Printing Options](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-excel-2007s-scale-to-fit-printing-optio.html)

Comment: OK. it means that for example if fit the width to twp pages it print in the way that width of work sheet print in to to paper and and if we fit its height to two pages it print worksheet in the way that the height print in two papers.